# Reactivity when element added to DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks, mutation-observers

I want to integrate [qr-scanner](https://github.com/nimiq/qr-scanner) to my project. This library is capable of decoding QR-Codes by utilizing the camera. It just needs the reference to a html-video-element and then renders the webcam-stream and optionally some indicators of a QR-code being found to this element.

The easiest component would be something like this:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import QrScanner from "qr-scanner";

export const QrComponent = () => {
  const videoElement = useRef(null);
  const scanner = new QrScanner(videoElement.current, (result) => {
    console.log(result)
  }) 

  return (
    <video ref={videoElement} />
  )
}
```

however, qr-scanner [checks, if the passed target-element is already part of the DOM](https://github.com/nimiq/qr-scanner/blob/master/src/qr-scanner.ts#L185):

```
if (!document.body.contains(video)) {
    document.body.appendChild(video);
    shouldHideVideo = true;
}
```

the video-element will never be added to the DOM, when the QrScanner-object is created. This leads to `shouldHideVideo` being set to true, which disables the video altogether later in the library-code.

So I think I need some kind of way to react to the video-element being added to the DOM. I thougt about using a MutationObserver (and tried it out by stealing the hook from [this page](https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-to-custom-react-hooks-with-mutationobserver/)), however I only wanted to print out all mutations using the hook like this:

```
import { useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import QrScanner from "qr-scanner";
import { useMutationObservable } from "./useMutationObservable";

export const QrComponent = () => {
  const videoElement = useRef(null);
  const scanner = new QrScanner(videoElement.current, (result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })

  const onMutation = useCallback((mutations) => console.log(mutations), [])
  useMutationObservable(document, onMutation)

  return (
    <video ref={videoElement} />
  )
}
```

however, I never got a single line printed, so to me it seems, as if there are no mutations there.

Did I maybe misunderstand something? How can I react to the video-element being added to the document?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I didn't provide enough information, but I found it out on my own:

The `MutationObserver` doesn't work, because I told it to watch `document`, yet I'm actually inside of a shadowdom with this particular component! So I suspect that mutations to the shadowdom won't be detected.

Also, because I'm inside of a shadowdom, `document.contains(videoElem.current)` will never be true. So in this particular case I have no better choice, than to copy the code of qr-scanner into my project-tree and adapt as needed.

On another note: `useLayoutEffect` is a react-hook, that is scheduled to run after DOM-mutations. So that's what I would use if I had to start over with this idea.